# Building intuition for the AC Stark shift

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

The AC Stark shift is a pretty ubiquitous phenomenon in atomic physics that describes the shift of energy levels in the presence of a periodic drive (usually it's due to laser light).

In the common perturbative regime, one can approximate the AC Stark shift with second order perturbation theory. This procedure gives you terms like $$\Delta \omega \sim \frac{\Omega^2}{\Delta}$$ where $\Omega$ is the Rabi frequency ($\propto d\cdot E$) and $\Delta$ is the detuning from the atomic transition.

Some of the major lessons of the AC Stark shift are

1. Drives with frequency smaller than the transition frequency will cause the ground state to lower in energy and the excited state to increase. The opposite occurs for drives faster than the transition frequency
2. The AC Stark shift is linear in power (second order in electric field)
3. The net shift is a total sum over terms like $\Omega^2/\Delta$ for all excited states accessible from the ground state.

Over the years I've grown to accept the math, but recently I've found it a bit difficult to convey these concepts intuitively. I tried explaining it to a student in terms of driving a harmonic oscillator with detuning, but it wasn't straightforward to explain the typical effects associated with the AC Stark shift.

My question is **what are some intuitive and valuable ways of understanding the AC Stark shift in general**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am partial to a hand-wavy picture that is heavily inspired by Brian Skinner's [exposition of Raman scattering](https://gravityandlevity.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/spare-me-the-math-raman-scattering/) (go there for nice animations of that related process).

So, imagine that an applied AC electric field induces an electric dipole in the electron. The dipole energy has the usual form of $U=-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{E}$, but in this case the dipole moment is itself proportional to the electric field, since it is an induced dipole, leading to an energy proportional to $|\vec{E}|^2$.

The induced dipole has a natural frequency, which is the atomic transition. In the case of the AC Stark shift, the external field also has an associated frequency. Just like a driven harmonic system, when you drive the dipole very slowly it can move smoothly with the changing field, and the two stay aligned. This leads to a negative energy as seen in the expression above. When you drive it above the natural frequency it cannot keep up, and turns out to oscillate out of phase with the applied field, leading to a positive overall sign for $U$.

That gives you properties 1) and 2). I am not as troubled by property 3) but I suppose I would appeal to superposition and Fourier decomposition to try to argue that once you've analyzed this for one detuning from resonance, you can extend it to others.

Comment: Thanks! One confusing thing about the harmonic oscillator approach in this context is that the complex linear response function of a HO is $\chi\sim 1/(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)$, rather than a $1/\Delta$ expected from the AC Stark shift expression. Any intuition for the discrepancy?

Comment: Actually after thinking, I suppose they should be the same in the limit $\Delta <<\omega_0$

Comment: Part 3 of the question was mainly around the functional form of the shift, but now that I see it comes from Taylor expanding the SHO response, it all fits nicely. Thanks!